# How to export html files inside the build folder in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How to export html files inside the build folder in next.js.?
I have export it, but it gave me .js extention files and I need .html files

[image: screenshot for your reference]

Answer (score 0):

Next.js supports static exports by default.

Mention the `output` as `export` in your `next.config.js`. And run the `next build` command.

#### Reference

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports